Nginx location not working when changing php page
I don't understand why the below Nginx config allows me to get to my index.php ok:


http://localhost:8080/nesting/index.php


but all dependencies of that page, like css, img keep pointing at http://localhost:8080/... So everything looks broken.
Likewise when moving on to another page it keeps pointing at the root url.
How to make the subdirectory persistent?
server {
listen 8080;

server_name localhost;
root /var/www/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

# compression setting
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 5;
gzip_min_length 100;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml 
application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript text/json;

 location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
   set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info; # because of bug http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
   try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
   include fastcgi_params;

   fastcgi_index index.php;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
   fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$path_info;
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
   fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $http_host;
}

location /nesting/ {
   alias /var/www/html/nesting/;
   index admin.php index.php;
}


In order to made your assets accessible when your index.php file along with its assets is placed in any nested directory, the resulting HTML document should refer its assets using relative URLs (e.g. ./style.css or style.css) rather than absolute ones (e.g. /style.css).

Assets within the web app are already refered with relative path.
When subdirectory is configured in Apache with the below it's working. Not in Nginx.
`DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
<Directory "/var/www/html">
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted

Alias /nesting"/var/www/html/nesting/"
<Directory "/var/www/html/nesting/">
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
`
